# An async fetch framework for Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, fetch

In [Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) section of Redux help, there is code like:

```
{
  selectedSubreddit: 'frontend',
  postsBySubreddit: {
    frontend: {
      isFetching: true,
      didInvalidate: false,
      items: []
    },
    reactjs: {
      isFetching: false,
      didInvalidate: false,
      lastUpdated: 1439478405547,
      items: [ ... ]
    },
}
```

There is a pattern of using `isFetching`, `didInvalidate`, `lastUpdated` -- I was wondering if there is a JS library which does exactly that? I think Relay is too much for what I'm trying to achieve.